# Best practices for creating thumbnails with GAE's Image API

Tags: image, google-app-engine, thumbnails

For each photo in my datastore, I'm creating 3 thumbnails (small, medium, and large). I'm having a hard time figuring out what API functions to use on the original photos to get a balance between quality and file size for the thumbnails. The file size for the thumbs always seems to be too large.

GAE's Image API has many options for images (such as im_feeling_lucky(), converting from PNG to JPEG, and adjusting JPEG quality) and I'd like to know what functions to use and in which order to achieve the optimal setting for these thumbnails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is simply to use `get_serving_url` to get a public URL for a scaled version of the image you can use as a thumbnail. This removes the need for you to create and separately store thumbnailed images.

Comment: This is a good solution, however there are major drawbacks to get_serving_url...You can't protect the URL (and thus it could drain your entire bandwidth quota) and if you have many images on a page it has to call get_serving_url multiple times, creating many milliseconds of latency.

Comment: @yourfriendzak If you have many images, you need to look up many things regardless. You can cache or even permanently store the result of get_serving_url, too.

Comment: You're right Nick, and it's a good solution. However there is still a major "no private urls" security hole with the result of get_serving_url(). The URL can't be protected unless the images blobkey is deleted (and even then there's a 24 hour lag) Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: @yourfriendzak No, currently it's only suitable for images you want to serve publicly.